# Regex for Currency Validation through preventDefault

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation, angular-directive

I'm writing some JS for input validation on currency and would like to block the user from entering any characters into the input that are outside of a set of rules. Code is not working as I would have thought and would love another opinion on how to approach.

For example-- I am currently focused into an input textbox and am typing characters into the same textbox, if I were to type anything outside of a minus sign, a period, or numbers, as the user types into the input box nothing will appear.

1. Minus sign ('-') can appear only at the beginning of a phrase, and only once
2. Once a '.' is used, it cannot be used again and only 0, 1, or 2 numbers should be able to follow after

Example Legal Inputs (attempting to type):

- 100.00 should be 100.00
- -100.00 should be -100.00
- 100 should be 100
- 100.5 should be 100.5
- 100..5 should be 100.5
- 100-10 should be 10010
- 1000.101 should be 1000.10

I'm using this code:

```
    element.on('keypress', function(event) {
        var pattern = /^([-]?[\d]*[.]{1}[\d]{1,2})$/;
        var charCode = event.which | event.keyCode;
        var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        if (!pattern.test(charStr)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

where `pattern` is the RegEx expression I am using that should cover these rules. Unfortunately, though it successfully blocks the types of characters it is not the case with frequencies (i.e. if I type in '---' this is legal input where my rules want only the first '-' to be allowed and successive attempts blocked).

Any ideas?

Comment: You are testing a single char against the whole regex. Do you have to enforce live validation? An alternative idea is to use the regex in a "pattern" attribute, i.e. `<input type="text" pattern="-?\d*\.\d{1,2}"/>`.

Comment: Yes live validation is what I am hoping to achieve here. That regex doesn't seem to work for the '-' and '.' either... I'm thinking another way of approaching this is to check the input for those characters and preventDefault specifically for those cases. Would this be necessary or should I be able to achieve this result through Regex?